# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at

Tags: javascript

Вот код,

```
moment.locale('en');
console.log(moment(1316116057189).fromNow());
console.log(moment.locales());
var input = document.querySelector('.c-datepicker-input');
var picker = new MaterialDatePicker().on('submit', function (val) {
  input.value = val.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
});

input.addEventListener('focus', function () {
  return picker.open();
});
```

Почему пишет ошибку?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at

Comment: `if(input){
input.addEventListener('focus', function () {
  return picker.open();
})
}else{
alert "nope"
}`

Comment: Потому что такого элемента нет на странице

Comment: if(input){ input.addEventListener('focus', function () { return picker.open(); }) }else{ alert "nope" }
не работает так(

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string 
 else{ alert "none" }

Comment: alert("nope"); очепятался, но это уж сами могли подправить?